# How to customise the Labels' header in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

As silly as this may sound but I can't seem to be able to customise the Labels' Header, in Blogger. I've tried various different methods and tags to achieve the look I want but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I've tried inserting CSS coding between the  tags but to no avail. The following piece of coding hasn't worked either.

```
.post-labels { 
letter-spacing: 0.09em !important;
font: arial 8px #666666 !important;
text-transform: uppercase !important;
margin: -1% 0% -1% 0% !important;
} 

.post-labels a { 
font-weight: normal!important; 
text-decoration: none!important; 
}
```

I have tried the following opening tags also but none of them seem to work:

```
#post-labels a {
#post-labels {
.post-labels a {
 .post-labels {
```

And I've also tried adding "!important" at the end of each element however even that hasn't worked. What surprises me is that some elements seem to work whereas the others do not. For example the text-align, text-transform, font-weight and text-decoration elements work but the font (size, family & color), letter-spacing and margin elements do not. I've tried every possible variation I could possibly think of but I can't seem to achieve the look I want for the Labels' header.

The URL for my blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: you are talking about hauls or SLEEK AND RIMMEL MINI HAUL? you want to change their css?

Comment: Thank you for getting in touch. However I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please post answer so others may benefit in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
font: arial 8px !important;
color: #666666 !important;
```

Instead of

```
font: arial 8px #666666 !important;
```

Because CSS Syntax for `font` property doesn't include the color. Also, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` values don't work with `<span>` element(unless you give it a `float`).

Apart from these, I see everything is working fine.